# Why can't I remove liquidity from my Uniswap v2 Pool?

Tags: uniswap, smart-contract-wallets, liquidity-provider

Token contract: 0x8b11461af2f7bc36ac3bbaff273b08485abe3bba
Pair contract: 0x01007f8c2e88626932e30fed121e6090be7015a3

I tried to remove my added liquidity through uniswap however, MetaMask doesn't pop up after I confirm to remove liquidity.

Based on the contracts, does anyone know why I currently can't remove my liquidity?

Answer (score 1):

You're hitting a require statement somewhere in your code. Hard to say which one without a transaction to check. My guess would be

```
        // check max wallet
        if (to != pool)
            require(balanceOf(to) + amount <= maxWallet(), "wallet maximum");
```

In beforeTokenTransfer() (l.539), since it doesnt exempt the owner wallet.

Comment: And if i'm right, because of the way maxWallet() works, it's gonna be there  for quite some time unless you find a workaround. Have fun anyways